# getting string from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am having a problem with this code, could someone help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{ 

   $obj = $.get('getSesion.php',function(data){  } );
   //$dato=JSON.stringify(obj);
    //$dato=dojo.toJson(obj);
    alert($obj);         
    if($obj != 'NULL')
    {
        $('#apDiv7').load('logeado.php');

    }else{

        $('#apDiv7').load('deslogeado.php');

    }
}
);
</script>
```

The problem is that from $obj I get `[object Object]`. I searched how to convert it but I had no success.

MORE DETAILS. From data I can get a number (0-infinite) or the string NULL. Depend on what value I get, in `apDiv7` I will load login window or a window's user connected.

I tried

```
var data =$obj.d;
```

but i get "undefined" string

Console log 
http://imageshack.com/a/img46/4004/ufgv.jpg

Solution for this case:

```
var msg = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "getSesion.php", async: false}).responseText;
```

Comment: Your function is returning a set of data , try iterating over it.

Comment: Try `console.log($obj);` instead of `alert` to see what the object is, then you should be able to pull the string from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.get` is an async call, so you should be doing this logic in the callback:

```
$.get('getSesion.php',function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Always use `console.log` so you can actually expand the complex object. Then simply reference the property names of the `data` response object.

Comment: Thank you Mr tymeJV for your answer but nothing happen when i use console.log(data);